# Draw polygons with Plotly and Choropleth

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I want to draw a high number of polygons with different colors.

Using `add_shapes` generates plots which are way to slow.

I suspect that using choropleth would work well enough. Currently, I have the following code:

```py
import plotly.express as px

polygons = [[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1)],
            [(3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 4), (4, 3), (3, 3)],
            [(5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 6), (6, 5), (5, 5)],
            [(7, 7), (7, 8), (8, 8), (8, 7), (7, 7)]]

geojson = {'features': [], 'type': 'FeatureCollection'}
ids = []
for index, poly in enumerate(polygons):
    temp_dict = {
        'geometry': {
            'coordinates': [polygons[index].copy()],
            'type': 'Polygon'},
        'type': 'Feature',
        'id': index}
    geojson['features'].append(temp_dict)
    ids.append(index)

fig = px.choropleth(
        geojson=geojson,
        color=ids,
        locations=ids)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0})
fig.show()
```

It seems to work, but I'd like to remove the map in the background, since my polygons are not related to geographic locations. Is there a way to do it or to get an equivalent result?

Comment: I don't know how slow it is, but if you use the scatter fill function to loop through the list of polygons, you will get the desired shape. `fig = go.Figure();for i, poly in enumerate(polygons):
    x = [x[0] for x in poly]
    y = [x[1] for x in poly]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, fill='toself'))
fig.show()`

Comment: @r-beginners the issue with scatter is that the size of the shapes on the screen doesn't change when the zoom level changes

Comment: @fontanf can you explain what you mean when you say "the size of the shapes don't change when you change the zoom level"? when you change the zoom level [here](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#shapedrawing-with-scatter-traces), the size of the shapes are adjusted according to the zoom level

Comment: @DerekO yes indeed. I meant using scatter points instead of shapes. The issue when using scatter to draw the shapes is the same as with add_shape: it's way to slow. I would like to be able to plot up to $10^5$ shapes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using choropleth polygons is a great idea, you just need one thing to [get rid of the base map](https://plotly.com/python/map-configuration/#disabling-base-maps) :

```py
fig.update_geos(visible=False)
```

NB. `fig.update_geo(...)` is a shortcut for `fig.update_layout(geo=dict(...))`.

@see also [Python Figure Reference: `layout.geo`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/geo/)